# how to read and parse raw data coming from TCP connection using node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, tcp

I want to use node.js to read and parse raw data that is send over TCP coming from a server that is continuously sending updated data every second.

i tried websocket first, but my embedded server does not provide a websocket handshake.

```
var WebSocket = require('ws')
var ws = new WebSocket("ws://1.100.0.250:9396");
ws.on('open', function open() {
ws.send('{abc123}');
});

ws.on('message', function incoming(data) {
console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Post some code that you've tried, and let us know what's not working.

Answer (score 1):

Websockets are not plain TCP sockets. If your server uses the latter, use [`net.connect()`](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_net_connect_port_host_connectlistener).